# How to use the user_passes_test decorator in class based views?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to check certain conditions before the user is allowed to see a particular user settings page. I am trying to achieve this using the user_passes_test decorator. The function sits in a class based view as follows. I am using method decorator to decorate the get_initial function in the view.

```
class UserSettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    success_url = '.'
    template_name = 'accts/usersettings.html'

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.profile.is_student:
            return form1
        if self.request.user.profile.is_teacher:
            return form2
        if self.request.user.profile.is_parent:
            return form3

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(test_settings, login_url='/accounts/usertype/'))
    def get_initial(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_obj = get_user_model().objects.get(email=self.request.user.email)
            if user_obj.profile.is_student:
                return { ..........
       ...... ....
```

Below is the test_settings function:

```
def test_settings(user):
    print "I am in test settings"
    if not (user.profile.is_student or user.profile.is_parent or user.profile.is_teacher):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I am getting the below error with the decorator.

```
File "../django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "../django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "../braces/views.py", line 107, in dispatch
  request, *args, **kwargs)
File "../django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
  return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "../django/views/generic/edit.py", line 162, in get
  form = self.get_form(form_class)
File "../django/views/generic/edit.py", line 45, in get_form
  return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
File "../django/views/generic/edit.py", line 52, in get_form_kwargs
  'initial': self.get_initial(),
File "../django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
  return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error. Am I applying the decorator on the wrong function? Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Django 1.9 has authentication mixins for class based views. You can use the [`UserPassesTest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) mixin as follows.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class UserSettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self):
        return test_settings(self.request.user)

    def get_login_url(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return super(UserSettingsView, self).get_login_url()
        else:
            return '/accounts/usertype/'
```

Note that in this case you have to override [`get_login_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.get_login_url), because you want to redirect to a different url depending on whether the user is not logged in, or is logged in but fails the test.

For Django 1.8 and earlier, you should decorate the `dispatch` method, not `get_initial`.

```
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(test_settings, login_url='/accounts/usertype/')) 
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(UserSettingsView,  self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: For Django 2, `is_authenticated()` is changed to `is_authenticated`