# Transform Function in Class Based View with decorator in Django

Tags: django, authentication, decorator, mixins

I have this code:

```
#decorators.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def superuser_required(func):
    return user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated() and u.is_superuser)(func)



# views.py
@superuser_required
def dashboard_candidates(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'persons': persons})
```

How to transform this function in ListView adapting the decorator?

I try:

```
PersonList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView)
    model = Person
    paginate_by = 10
```

I do not know how to implement the decorator mentioned above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the user\_passes\_test decorator in class based views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682704/how-to-use-the-user-passes-test-decorator-in-class-based-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engraçado, só funcionou desse jeito.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


class SuperuserRequiredMixin(object):

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated() and u.is_superuser))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SuperuserRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class PersonList(SuperuserRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Person
    paginate_by = 20
```