# A user can manually edit another user view from URL

Tags: python, django

I just noticed that a user can manually access another users update profile view by changing to the other users pk or username(as slug) in the URL.
for instance

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/dashboard/18/updateprofile
```

Lets say that is the users update profile url, if this user changes the pk to 19 and edit, the user with pk 19 profile will be edited, is this a bug or is this an error from my side? Thank you.

my view here

```
class ProfilepdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = 'userlogin'
    fields = ('age', 'location')
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'account/updateprofile.html'
    success_message = "Your profile was successfully updated"
```

url

```
path('account/dashboard/<int:pk>/updateprofile', views.ProfilepdateView.as_view(), name="updateprofile"),
```

Comment: This seems like it's really a question about web design and security, not a question about programming.

Comment: Thats how [moonpig exposed customers data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgJudU_jlZ8), whether its a feature or a bug depends on your application.

Comment: Django doesn't know who is allowed to access the view, it's up to you to take care of that in the view. If you [edit] your question to include your view and URL pattern then we can suggest how to restrict access.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know, now I understand that  django doesn't know who is allowed to access the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all my able BOSSES and MASTERS, this was what I added to my view to solve the problem.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    profile= super().get_queryset()
    return profile.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

The final view is like this

```
class ProfilepdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = 'userlogin'
    fields = ('age', 'location')
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'account/updateprofile.html'
    success_message = "Your profile was successfully updated"

    def get_queryset(self):
        profile= super().get_queryset()
        return profile.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you to control who can do what and where - Django cannot guess this. You have two solutions here:

1/ keep your url as it is but check if the current user (`request.user`) is allowed to edit this profile:

```
def update_profile(request, profile_id):
    # assume that profile as a onetone to User
    profile = get_object_or_404(pk=profile_id)
    if request.user != profile.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    # your code here
```

2/ remove the profile_id from the url and use `request.user` to get the current user's profile

```
def update_profile(request, profile_id):
    # assume that profile as a onetone to User
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    # your code here
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's a generic view not a function based view, what do you suggest? I updated the question to show the view. Thank you

Comment: I actually avoid CBVs as much as possible - most of the time they only make things uselessly complicated, and they really don't help newcomers... Now instead of a very simple change in a very simple function, you have to find which method of which of the dozen or so parent classes you have to override.

Comment: Or better: use the `UserPassesTest` mixin, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682704/how-to-use-the-user-passes-test-decorator-in-class-based-views

Answer (score 1):

With this, other users would still be able to access other users page, but wouldn't be able to update it. If you originally wanted only the owner of a profile to be able to access the update page, then you could restrict view in template.

```
    {% if object.user == user %} Show Page Content {% endif %}
```

or right in the view.

Comment: Thanks bro I know this, I just wanted to handle it in the view and not in the template.  didn't want the information to be rendered to the page at all.

It's only a sneaker user that will manually change the pk in the url, so with this GET_QUERYSET function if a sneaker user tries to do this he will be sent to a 404 page. Personally I think this is better than letting a sneaky user have access to the page even if he doesn't see the information.

Comment: Yeah.. Sometimes, I purposely restrict the sneaky user right in the template just to taunt the user. Like, put a notification about the user being sneaky.